# GCP Datastore Dashboard says "Project does not exist"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, datastore

After some testing calls to Google Datastore from our GKE cluster (unfortunately, cannot tell exactly what the calls were), we experienced a strange problem with our Datastore.

When entering the Datastore Dashboard, there's the usual two dropdowns for *namespace* and *kind*, but below that we have a red-tinted info "The project mosaiqio does not exist".

Any ideas what would happen, and - more importantly how to fix this issue? We'd rather avoid recreating everything related to the project.

[image: The Datastore Dashboard - project does not exist]

[image: The Datastore Entities - no namespaces]

[image: The Datastore Admin not accessible]

Comment: Assuming you're using Chrome, can you check what the [Network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) of the developer tools reveals? Does the HTTP requests sent for data reveal any new information? Is the Datastore data still available from different access points like the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/) or [Python API](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/)?